# Visualize polygon above the image of EVI index in R

Tags: r, modis, evi

I have MODIS images for the EVII index, with a polygon shapefile for specific areas in my area :

files MODISEVI

[MODISEVI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mSxJ.png)

all polygons

[image: all polygons]

polygon

[image: polygon]

The images of NDVI and the polygons have the same projection:

```
> proj4string(data.shape)
[1] "+proj=utm +zone=21 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
> 
> proj4string(r)
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

My problem is that I can't overlay my polygon on my NDVI images.

I tried this script but did not work:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(tiff)

r <- raster("D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000209_aid0001.tif")
str_name <- "MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000209_aid0001.tif"
imported_raster <- raster(str_name)
plot(r)

# importer les fichiers shapefil
data.shape <- readOGR(dsn = "D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/", layer = "2001")
plot(data.shape, border = "red")

# vector-raster
plot(r)
plot(data.shape, col = "red", border = "black", add = TRUE)
```

I would like to know how I can visualize my polygon above the image?

I have already visualized my image and the polygons above on the image in QGIS and it works but I have to zoom on the polygons to visualize them well, the thing that does not exist can not be on R.

[image]

[image]
[image]

---

@BrunoConteLeite I tried your suggestion and it works,  but i have another question.  Do I have to load the new line for projection every time?
- another question is that when I tried your script to zoom on the limit of the polygon it gives me results like :

[image]

that, even if for the 1st polygon when I zoom it goes beyond the limits:

[image]

For  my objective I must extract the spectral profiles inside my polygon , but I do not know if I will have to delimit the area where are the polygons or just zoom before extract the spectral profiles?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can provide sample of your data

Comment: If you cant provide sample data then *at least* show the output of "summary" on the data, or anything that gives us the bounding box and projections of the objects. Otherwise we can't really help.

Comment: yes i can  provide my data : i have 2 data 1 for imag MODIS EVI and second for shapfil polygon for some areas in my area

Comment: my problem i can't  visualize my plygon above the imag , may be because it so small ? sorry i can't speak english verry well

Comment: @Spacedman    how can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to plot the `raster.tif` file and the polygons contained in the `MLI_adm0.shp` shapefile of this hypothetical [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zg5pasnqfo93u0/data.zip?dl=0). Load them in R

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

r <- raster('raster.tif')
data.shape <- readOGR('.', 'MLI_adm0')
```

As you mentioned, you must make sure that they have the same projection. It seems that it is not the case in your data -- your `data.shape` seems to be projected at UTM zone 21 and your raster not (double check that). To make sure they have the same projection, use `projectRaster()` for the raster and `spTransform()` for the polygon(s) as follows

```
r <- projectRaster(r, crs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
data.shape <- spTransform(data.shape, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))
```

make sure that they are correctly projected now

```
r@crs
> CRS arguments:
>  +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

data.shape@proj4string
> CRS arguments:
>  +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Now they can be put in a plot together. Use the options `xlim` and `ylim` to "zoom into" the area of your polygons. If not, the area in the plot is the one of the raster, as in the figure below.

```
plot(r)
plot(data.shape, add = T)
```

[image: plot with no zoom]

A nice trick to zoom the plot within the boundaries of the polygon `data.shape` is to use the `bbox()` function to obtain the boundaries automatically. Set the limits when calling the plot of the raster, as follows

```
plot(r,
    xlim=c(bbox(data.shape)[1], bbox(data.shape)[3]),
    ylim= c(bbox(data.shape)[2], bbox(data.shape)[4])
)
plot(data.shape, add = T)
```

You should obtain something like

[image: plot with zoom]

Comment: i have posted i result , but i have some question